# Event after get property in C#

Tags: c#, class, model

I need event after get property.

For example I want something like this

```
public class ModelClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

OnBeforGet Function

```
public void OnBeforGet()
{
    Title = "Value";
}
```

Use Prop

```
public void Test()
{
    using (var modelClass = new ModelClass())
    {
        var title = modelClass.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem ?. Put the code you're having trouble with because your example doesn't even compile

Comment: I don't problem. I want to know can we have OnBeforGet Event or no. The code I wrote was for example

Comment: You can use `get;` method even if you want to apply a change there. see this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/get

Comment: I know but I want to write `get;` for all prop in class. for example If a new property is added, this event will be active for it

Comment: Well, if you don't want to write property getters with the desired logic yourself, you may want to seek some code generator that automatically generates the get-method logic you need for the properties you desire. If you are unable to find a suitable code generator, you either have to write such a code generator yourself (don't ask me about it; it's not trivial) or accept that you will have to write the get-methods of the affected properties by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.
every call of 'Title' prop the 'OnBeforGet()' function will be fired

```
public class ModelClass
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            OnBeforGet();
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            this._title = value;
        }
    }

    public void OnBeforGet()
    {
        Title = "value Updated Before Get function";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , But I want to write `get;` for all prop in class. for example If a new property is added, this event will be active for it

Comment: you can repeat the same function for other props like 

 private string _description;
 public string Description
 {
  get
  {
   OnBeforGet();
   return _description;
  }
  set
  {
   this._description = value;
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a better way to do this once for all classes

Comment: You are welcome, hope you find your answer soon.